# Getting NullPointerException at the beginning of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm not sure why I'm getting a nullPointerException at the beginning of my array (see last println) when I print it out. I've seen a nullPointException before but it was at the end of an array. I don't get why it's at the beginning. Plus, I would appreciate it if someone could help be get rid of the exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("Book.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        Book[] books = new Book[20];

        int x = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            int id, year;
            String name, author;

            //scan data for each book and create new book object
            id = Integer.valueOf(sc.next());
            year = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine().trim());
            name = sc.nextLine();
            author = sc.nextLine();

            books[x] = new Book(id, name, year, author);
            x++;
        }

        for(Book b : books){
            System.out.println(b.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's at the beginning and not at the end? The program is going to crash with an NPE if fewer than 20 books are entered, and with an Index Out of Bound if more than 20 books are entered.

Comment: It makes no sense to tell us there's an NPE w/o indicating precisely which line, and what's null. How about putting in some printlns to check your assumptions about the data or using a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is very fragile. It expects the file of exactly 20 books: if fewer than 20 books are entered, you will get a null pointer exception in the printing loop; if more than 20 books are entered, you will get an array index out of bounds exception in the reading loop.

You should change the `for-in` loop with a simple `for`, and add a limit to the number of books that you read from the file, like this:

```
while(sc.hasNext() && x < 20) {
    ...
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != x ; i++) {
    System.out.println(books[i].toString());
}
```

The program restructured as above is a lot less forgiving: rather than crashing when fewer than 20 books are entered, it would print as many entries as there are in the file. When more books are in the file than could fit in your pre-allocated array, books after the 20-th one are quietly ignored.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't programmed in Java for months. I'm extremely rusty now. I don't know how to break the rust now :(